# ООП, Прототипы, конвертор валют

Tags: javascript, ооп, прототипное-наследование

**Есть задача**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Пример реализации**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть в целом если не лезть в глубину реализация верная и возвращает нужные значения. Но есть, как всегда одно но...
Если я вывожу в консоль новые объекты ( у них остаются дефолтное значение currency, и как бы я не старался он хочет в новом объекте изменяться.
В другом случае если меняю через контекст, вообще все ломается, меняется значение в исходном объекте и дальше все идет не пол плану.

```js
const Money = function money(value, currency = 'usd') {
  this.value = value;
  this.currency = currency;
}

Money.prototype.getValue = function getValue() {
  return this.value;
}

Money.prototype.exchangeTo = function exchangeTo(currency) {
  if (currency === 'eur') {
    return new Money(this.getValue() * 0.7);
  } else {
    return new Money(this.getValue() * 1.2);
  }

}

Money.prototype.add = function add(object) {
  if (this.currency !== object.currency) {
    return new Money(this.getValue() + object.exchangeTo(this.currency).getValue())
  } else {
    return new Money(this.getValue() + object.getValue());
  }
}

const money1 = new Money(100);
console.log(money1);
console.log(money1.getValue());
console.log(money1.exchangeTo('eur').getValue());

const money2 = new Money(200, 'eur');
console.log(money2);
console.log(money2.getValue());

const money3 = money2.add(money1);
console.log(money3);
console.log(money3.getValue());

console.log(money1);

const money4 = money1.add(money2);
console.log(money4.getValue());
console.log(money4);
```

Comment: Вы метод `add` неправильно реализовали. Вы почему-то решили, что `this.currency` всегда `usd`. Нужно в `new Money(..., this.currency)` второй параметр передавать.

Comment: Зачем это делать через прототипы для функции, когда можно использовать класс?

Comment: Я не сам себе придумал это задание, я только учусь. Я знаю что лучше через класс и конструктор. Но до этого я ещё не дошёл. Поэтому так.

Comment: если я правильно вас понял, то после создания нового объекта через метод add у вас остается значение валюту по умолчанию. Ну так вы же и не задаете эту валюту, то есть не передаете ее параметром

Comment: @DenisLopatin, да, все верно.  Но я не понимаю как верно реализовать метод (exchangeTo). Он принимает одно значение, и как передать в новый объект это значение не могу сообразить.

Comment: @pank Спасибо, со скрипом) но  разобрался) я не туда передавал просто параметр) сообразил, что ты(вы) пытался до меня донести.

Comment: попробуйте передать object.currency вторым параметром в метод add